# Not able to get the answer for question from Influx DB using python Langchain package and LLM

Tags: python, influxdb, langchain, large-language-model

- Influx DB contains the required usage data in numerical format.
- Python langchain package SQLDatabase() API does not support InfluxDB to connect directly, it supports other databases (like postgres, mysql)
- So trying to convert the influx db query JSON o/p to PDF and read the PDF into chunks with langchain vector DB embeddings.
- Getting error while read/write the pdf. So currently generated the PDF manually with sample query JSON output.
- But always getting the answer as 'I don't know'.

sample code:
`   question="what is the todays vehicle sale?"

```
#influxDB query output for today's vehicle sale is written into pdf and loading PDF
loaders = [PyPDFLoader(file_path)]

index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(
    embedding=HuggingFaceEmbeddings(),
    text_splitter=CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=100)).from_loaders(loaders)

chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=model,
                                    chain_type="stuff",
                                    retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(),
                                    input_key="question")
# Invoke the chain
response_text = chain.run(question)
print(response_text)`
```

- Expecting the proper answer for questions.
- Is there any way to connect Influx database from python langchain package SQLDatabase() API?
- Do we need to process the database query output instead of JSON to some other format before feeding to model as PDF? how?